# Final variable and synchronized block in java

Tags: java, variables, final, synchronized

What is a final variable in Java? For example: if I write `final int temp;` in function what is the meaning of the final keyword?
Also, when would I want to use final variable (both as a class variable and as a function variable)?
Why must variables in a synchronized block be declared final?

Comment: @sb2367: I think you're getting confused with final classes, which can't be subclassed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Basically it just means you can't change the value. For instance variables, you have to assign any final variables once (and only once) in the constructor (or with a variable initializer). Synchronization is a pretty orthogonal concept.

The primary reason for making a *local* variable final is so you can use it in an anonymous inner class... this has nothing to do with being in a synchronized block.

Final variables *are* useful for immutable classes, admittedly - and immutability makes life easier in a multi-threaded environment - but that's the only relationship between the two that I can think of...

EDIT: Wildwezyr's comment makes sense in terms of not changing the variable *on which you are synchronizing*. That would be dangerous, for the reasons he's given. Is that what you meant by "variable in synchronized block"?

Comment: have you ever seen this warning: "Synchronization on non-final field"?

Comment: @WildWezyr: I haven't, but I understand why it would occur.

Comment: You might want to check out the post [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249917/final-variable-manipulation-in-java?rq=1) for clarity on the small but significant difference between a final object and a final primitive.

Comment: @HardcoreBro: There's no such thing as a "final object". There's only a final *variable* (or a final class, of course). It's important to distinguish between a variable, its value, and an object that the value may refer to.

Answer (score 16):

Final variables and synchronized code blocks do have something in common... If you declare non-final variable `a` and then write `synchronized (a) { System.out.println('xxx'); }` you will get warning "Synchronization on non-final field" - at least in NetBeans.

Why you should not be synchronizing on non-final field? Because if field value may change, then different threads may be synchronizing on different objects (different values of the field) - so there could be no synchronization at all (every thread may enter synchronized block at the same time).

Look here for example of real-life trouble caused by synchronizing on non-final field: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5379204

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Jon Skeet said, the value can't be changed but the contents may be changed.

```
final Integer one = new Integer(1);
...
one = new Integer(2); // compile error

final List list = new ArrayList();
...
list = new ArrayList(); // compile error
list.add(1); // Changes list, but that's fine!
```

Also be aware that final and static final are not the same. final is within the scope of the instance, whereas static final is the same for all instances of a class (in other languages this could be called a constant).

Personally I think the advantage of final, even when not absolutely required to get your software working, is in the semantical meaning. It offers you the possibility to say to the compiler *and the next person working on that code* that this variable is not meant to be changed, and that trying to change it could result in a bug.