# can I use synchronized to a final field?

Tags: java, final, synchronize

Consider following code, I want to make it a thread safe class, so that it will never get odd number:

```
class Test {
  private int value = 0;
  private final Object lock;

  public void add() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      value++;
      value++;
    }
  }

  public int getValue() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      return value;
    }
  } 
}
```

I am now doubt of the lock field, which is declared to be final, will this matter? or it will break the thread safety?

I think if the lock field is not declared to be final, this should be a thread-safe class. If this conclusion is wrong, please correct me, thank you.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101327/final-variable-and-synchronized-block-in-java) question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am now doubt of the lock field, which is declared to be final, will this matter?

Yes, its considered best practice to *only* lock `final` field objects.

If you can change the reference you can change which object is locked, breaking thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

Should be ok.  might even make it safer, since one cannot simply assign something else to the lock during execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ReadWriteLock to achieve the same result and with a safe implementation.

References:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=118

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to lock an instance, then final is acceptable.  Should you look to lock or put a mutex on a class, then make the variable static.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the synchonization is done by some hidden field of the lock object. Also final means, that the REFERENCE is final, not the object itself.

Example:

```
final Bar bar = new Bar(); //bar hase property lock
bar.lock = XYZ; //will work, object is not FINAL
bar = new Bar(); //fail, the reference is FINAL
```

Comment: For what it's worth, there is no built in construct to make 'objects final' in Java. Immutability must be enforced programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to synchronize multiple threads, they have to be synchronized based on the same object reference/instance. This ensures that they both synchronize at the same time based on the same data.

Hope that makes a bit of sense; you just have to synchronize based on a finalized variable rather than a dynamic one.

> If a method modifies a static field, you must synchronize access to
>   this field, even if the method is typically used only by a single
>   thread. It is not possible for clients to perform external
>   synchronization on such a method because there can be no guarantee
>   that unrelated clients will do likewise, [see](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK05-J.+Synchronize+access+to+static+fields+that+can+be+modified+by+untrusted+code).