# Do final (constant) instance (non-static) variables act like class (static) variables?

Tags: java, variables, scope, constants

In the following example, the variable `b` is declared `final`, but not `static`. That means it's a constant instance variable. However, because it's constant, none of the `Passenger` objects can change its value. So isn't it better to declare it `static` and make it a class variable, so that there is only one copy to be used by all instantiated objects?

```
class Passenger {
    int a;
    final int b = 0;

    void drive() {
        System.out.println("I'm driving!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 10):

The purpose of `final` but non-`static` variables is to have an object-wide constant. It should be initialized in the constructor:

```
class Passenger {
    final int b;

    Passenger(int b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

If you are always assigning a constant literal value (`0`) to the `final` variable, it doesn't make much sense. Using `static` is preferred so that you are only having a single copy of `b`:

```
static final int b = 0;
```

BTW I don't think having default access modifier was your intention.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of object-wide constants and initialization in the constructors.

Comment: Yes, I omitted the access modifiers for this example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the purpose of b. Usually constants are there for a specific purpose. If you make it static you could accidentally change it in some instance of that class and that will affect all the others.

Comment: But static variables can also be declared as final. So that will prevent that accidental modification.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple instances of `Passenger` class, I would go for making it static. While this has little benefit when talking about an `int` variable, this could save some memory if you have complex objects. This is because a static variable belongs to a class, not to an instance, thus memory space for it will be reserved only once, and it will be referred by the class object itself, not by the instances. Of course, you should be aware that having `b` as a static variable means that the changes made on this variable will be reflected on all the classes that access this variable, but since you made it `final` this won't be the case.

Note also that with the code you've written, classes in the same package as `Passenger` will be able to read the `b` value by accessing it via `Passenger.b` (if static).

Comment: Yes, saving memory for large variables was exactly my reason for declaring it static. I omitted the access modifiers in this example. I suspected a lot of people will notice that :D

Comment: Of course, if you have complex object, remember that only the reference will be final, but unless you make them immutable you can still change the internal state by operating on methods, if any are exposed. And this way, since the object is shared between all the instances, changes in the internal state will be reflected on all the readers of that object.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249917/final-variable-manipulation-in-java

Answer (score 0):

In java, the `static` attribute basically means: **associated with the type itself, rather than an instance of the type**.

In other words you can reference a static variable without creating instances of that type... Whereas in the case of just using `final` you'd need to instantiate the class.

So, yes, to answer your question, I'd say that you're right. :)

Answer (score 0):

A `final` primitive is the same as a `static final` primitive (except more efficient)

A `final` reference to an immutable object the same as a `static final` reference of the same.

A `final` reference to a mutable object is NOT the same as a `static final` reference of the same.

```
final int i = 0;
// same as
static final int = 0;

final String hi = "Hello";
// same as
static final String hi = "Hello";

final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// is NOT the same as
static final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The only time the last example is the same is when you have a singleton.  It is fairly common for singletons to be written with a confusion of static and non static fields and methods as the difference is not obvious. :|

Answer (score 0):

A `final` variable is defined when you need a constant, so you can assign a value just once.
Using `static`, instead, you are defining a variable shared by all the objects of that type (like a global variable) and it is not associated with a certain object itself.