# Declaring a List field with the final keyword

Tags: java, list, final

If I have the following statement within a class where `Synapse` is an abstract type:

```
private final List<Synapse> synapses;
```

Does `final` allow me to still be able to change the state of the `Synapse` objects in the `List`, but prevent me from adding new `Synapse` objects to the list? If I am wrong, could you please explain what `final` is doing and when I should be using the keyword `final` instead.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

No, the final keyword does not make the list, or its contents immutable. If you want an immutable List, you should use:

```
List<Synapse> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(synapses);
```

What the final keyword does is prevent you from assigning a new value to the 'synapses' variable. I.e., you cannot write:

```
final List<Synapse> synapses = createList();
synapses = createNewList();
```

You can, however, write:

```
List<Synapse> synapses = createList();
synapses = createNewList();
```

In essense, you can still change, add and remove the contents of the list, but cannot create a new list assigned to the variable synapses.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that although nothing can be added, removed, or replaced in `unmodifiableList` constructed like this, the elements of the list can still have their state changed (if they are mutable). Nothing about the list declaration or construction can prevent that.

Comment: So you could do: `final List<Synapse> synapses = createList();` and then do `synapses.add(newSynapse())`? Then it means `synapses` can't point to anything else but this list right?

Comment: @A.Vieira yes, right, as long as `synapses` is a mutable object like ArrayList.

Answer (score 9):

`final` prevents you from *reassigning* `synapses` after you've assigned it once - you can still add/remove elements as you would normally. You can read more about the `final` keyword [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29).

Answer (score 6):

You can still change, add and remove the contents of the list, but cannot create a new list assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once. Declaring a variable final can serve as useful documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid programming errors.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a final variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned (§16) immediately prior to the assignment.
>
> A blank final is a final variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.
>
> Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a final variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.

Therefore, if you wish to enforce that the state reachable through the variable does not change, you have to declare the variable `final`, use an unmodifiable List (for instance with [Collections.unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)), and make `Synapse` objects immutable.

Answer (score 1):

The final implementation implies that object reference once initiated, the reference itself can never be changed but the content can of course be. Its not violating the rules at all. You have specified only one rule about the reference change which is working accordingly. If you want the values should also never change you should go for immutable lists i.e

```
List<String> items = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

See the following related question.

- [Final variable manipulation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249917/1037210)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer explained all in theory here you can find code to run and see actual diffrence ,advisable to use loacal variable

```
package exp_test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class testList {
    final static List<String> synapses = new ArrayList();;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        synapses.add("A");
        System.out.println(synapses);
        //
        System.out.println(finalLisTest(synapses));
        //
        System.out.println(synapses);
        //
        synapses.add("B");

        List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(synapses);
        System.out.println(finalLisTest(unmodifiableList));
        //
        System.out.println(unmodifiableList);

    }

    private static List finalLisTest(List<String> list) {
        list.remove(0);
        return null;

    }

}
```

Results :

```
[A]
null
[]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.remove(Collections.java:1317)
    at exp_test.testList.finalLisTest(testList.java:29)
    at exp_test.testList.main(testList.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

A List with final keyword, still you can add as well as remove.
But you cannot copy the list into another list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).